# How to remove Location control feature in Ampiri SDK after using it

Tags: ios

I am currently using Ampiri to mediate ad networks in my application. I've implemented Location control feature for UICollectionView for native ads and it works but I can't find a way to remove them after a specific event has occurred (i.e Hiding Ads after users paid). Does anyone know how to do this?

This is the feature i'm using:
https://github.com/ampiri/ampiri-ios-sdk#location-control

Comment: Please include some code that you have so far and what you have tried

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following method:

```
- (void)deleteAds {
   self.adapter = nil;       
   self.collectionView.delegate = self;     
   self.collectionView.dataSource = self;     
   [self.collectionView reloadData];`    
}
```

Add this to collectionView delegate and dataSource class (UIViewController subclasses)

Thanks,